# How to interact with a button on a certain row of a ListView with custom adapter (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have a ListView which implements a custom adapter that contains a few TextViews and two Buttons.

Now when i try to add an item to that ListView, if it is already in the list i want to change the text of its row's TextView (Quantity) and make it + 1. But i can't quite figure out how to interact with that particular TextView.

Adapter code:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.lay_list_items);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.lay_list_items, null);

    final Item item = getItem(position);
    TextView nom = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNom);
    TextView description = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    final TextView qty = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    Button btnAjouter = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnAjouter);
    Button btnRetirer = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnRetirer);

    nom.setText(item.nom);
    description.setText(item.description);
    qty.setText("1");

    btnAjouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int qtyCourante = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
            int newQty = qtyCourante + 1;
            qty.setText(Integer.toString(newQty));
        }
    });

    btnRetirer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int qtyCourante = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
            int newQty = qtyCourante - 1;
            if (newQty > 0)
                qty.setText(Integer.toString(newQty));
            else
                ItemAdapter.super.remove(item);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the count, and then use it.

Use **`ArrayList<Integer>`** or add one more field **`int count`** in your Model Class Item. It is better to add one more field in Item class.

Initialize it as 1 for all items.

And use the code,

```
qty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCount()));//declare a method to get count field value, here getCount()
```

In your button click,

```
btnAjouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        item.setCount( item.getCount() + 1 ); //declare a method to set value
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And also

```
btnRetirer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( item.getCount() > 0)
            item.setCount( item.getCount() - 1 );
        else
            ItemAdapter.super.remove(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

**`notifyDataSetChanged();`** should be invoked to update your changes.

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well, i didn't know notifyDataSetChanged() existed hehe :^)

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an ArrayAdapter as your base Class, if you want to add a new item, you can just call:

```
adapter.add(newItem);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and the adapter will help you handle the new item.